# Нужно изменить код

Tags: c, циклы, for

Нужно изменить этот код так, чтобы ответ выводился в виде ромба, а не квадрата. Я не понимаю, как это можно сделать.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{  unsigned char n,k,symbol;
    for (n = 1; n<=5; n++)
    {
        symbol = 'I' - (n-2)*2;
        for (k = 1; k<=n-1; k++)
        {
            printf ("%2c", symbol);
            symbol = symbol + 2;
        }
        printf (" A");
        symbol = 'C';
        for (k = 1; k<=5-n; k++)
        {
            printf("%2c", symbol);
            symbol += 2;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Итоговый результат должен быть таким:

[image: результат]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну, самый тупой способ - [например](https://ideone.com/gXXzBT),

```
int main()
{
    for(int row = 0; row < 7; ++row)
    {
        int d = abs(row - 3);
        char c = 'D' - d;
        int spaces = 2*d;
        for(int i = 0; i < spaces; ++i) printf(" ");

        for(char q = c; q >= 'A'; --q) printf("%c ",q);
        for(char q = 'B'; q <= c; ++q) printf("%c ",q);
        puts("");
    }
}
```